# vb.net show tooltiptext for every item in datagridviewcombobox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tooltip, datagridviewcombobox

I have searched for displaying tooltiptext for datagridview but I'm only getting tooltiptext for datagridviewcell. What I want is the tooltiptext to display when an item is highlighted (mouse hover) from the dropdown list of a datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.
I have set the tooltiptext in databinding of the comboboxcolumn but it doesn't display anything in runtime.

```
'assuming dtExpense is the datatable used as datasource
With CType(DataGridView3.Columns(2), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
    .AutoComplete = True
    .DataSource = dtExpense
    .DisplayMember = "acct_title"
    .ValueMember = "acct_id"
    .DataPropertyName = "acct_id"
    .ToolTipText = "description"
End With
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this. In datagriviewcell.tooltiptext it has to drawn at some point. I was thinking how to do this with datagridviewcomboboxcolumn and it has to display for each item in the combobox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an object class with `string` properties named `acct_title` (to display as the dropdown items) and `description` (to display as tooltips on those dropdown items), you'll want to:

1. Add a ToolTip control to your Form.
2. Handle the `EditingControlShowing` event for the DataGridView to add event handlers to the underlying ComboBox.

   ```
   Me.DataGridView3.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView3_EditingControlShowing

   Private Sub DataGridView3_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
   If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
           Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
           cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed
           cb.DrawItem -= Cb_DrawItem
           cb.DrawItem += Cb_DrawItem
           cb.DropDownClosed -= Cb_DropDownClosed
           cb.DropDownClosed += Cb_DropDownClosed
       End If
   End Sub
   ```
3. Handle the ComboBox `DrawItem` event to set the ToolTip value and show it. We will use reflection to grab the `description` property off the dropdown items and set it's string value to the ToolTip.

   ```
   Private Sub Cb_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs)
       Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
       Dim item = cb.Items(e.Index)
       Dim display As String = cb.GetItemText(item)
       Dim toolText As String = item.[GetType]().GetProperty("description").GetValue(item, Nothing).ToString()

       e.DrawBackground()

       Using br As New SolidBrush(e.ForeColor)
           e.Graphics.DrawString(display, e.Font, br, e.Bounds)
       End Using

       If (e.State And DrawItemState.Focus) = DrawItemState.Focus AndAlso cb.DroppedDown Then 
           Me.toolTip1.Show(toolText, cb, e.Bounds.Right, e.Bounds.Bottom, 2000)
       End If

       e.DrawFocusRectangle()
   End Sub
   ```
4. Handle the ComboBox `DropDownClosed` event to hide the ToolTip.

   ```
   Private Sub Cb_DropDownClosed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       Dim cb As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
       Me.toolTip1.Hide(cb)
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I needed to change some lines of code since there's a lot of other comboboxes in my datagridview. I think its doing fine. But, I am getting a NullReferenceException around this line
`Dim toolText As String = item.[GetType]().GetProperty("description").GetValue(item, Nothing).ToString()`
I even check if `cb isNot Nothing` (although I think its not necessary since tooltip should show when item is hovered and not when selected) but this error still persist.
Do you think I need to add a datatype around here `Dim item = cb.Items(e.Index)`?

Comment: The only way I could replicate that error was if I did `.GetProperty("PropertyThatIsNotOnTheObject")`.  You could try putting a data type on `Dim item` but if I'm correct, that will just throw the same error. Make sure `GetProperty` is called with a string that is the name of the property you want to display in your toooltip.

Comment: I did set `.ToolTipText = "description"` in my datagridviewcomboboxcolumn property. That should be fine right? But I can't really get why I'm still getting NullReference. So, I did a workaround and I kinda search the `description` from the `Datasource` itself. I'm being very inefficient here but it did the work. Thank you for your help!!
But there's a little bit of a problem, can you still help me here? The tooltip displays at the very bottom of my screen since I have a very long list of account titles. How can I get it to display beside the combobox item?

Comment: Well, I investigated why this happened, I think its because the dropdown transfers to the top if there's not enough space below the combobox itself. And while that happens, `e.Bounds.Bottom` still thinks that the first item is still displayed just below the combobox. What I did is just subtract some amount from it to fix its Y-coordinate. I'm just not sure if this will hold up in difference screen resolutions since its not dynamic enough to adjust itself.

Comment: Sorry the tooltip location gave you grief.  In my tests it displayed aligned and to the right of the hovered dropdown item, but I'm glad to hear you found a workaround. Sorry for the slow response; I moved over the weekend.